# Tomography calculations by using tangent lines in a convex object

Tags: convex-analysis, tomography

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJJBx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wetyt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vYQH.png)

Above are problems i have to solve, here are more context that you may need :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92IGM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtUyH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqK8g.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSTyO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyWSS.png)

This is from a very old book about tomography and its pace in explanning things are too fast for me to understand. I would be very appreciated if someone help me out with this. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.